# Why do I get a MalformedInputException from this code?

Tags: scala

I'm a newbie in Scala, and I wanted to write some sourcecodes from myself for me to get better.
I've written a simple object (with a main entry) in order to simulate a "grep" call on all files of the current directory. (I launch the program from Eclipse Indigo, and in Debian Squeeze) :

```
package com.gmail.bernabe.laurent.scala.tests

import java.io.File

import scala.io.Source

object DealWithFiles {

  def main(args:Array[String]){
    for (result <- grepFilesHere(".*aur.*"))
      println(result)
  }

  private def grepFilesHere(pattern:String):Array[String] = {
    val filesHere = new File(".").listFiles

    def linesOfFile(file:File) =
      Source.fromFile(file).getLines.toList

    for (file <- filesHere;
        if file.isFile
    )
      yield linesOfFile(file)(0)
  }

}
```

But I get a java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException, which I am not able to solve :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:260)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:319)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
at scala.io.BufferedSource$BufferedLineIterator.hasNext(BufferedSource.scala:67)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:772)
at scala.io.BufferedSource$BufferedLineIterator.foreach(BufferedSource.scala:43)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:130)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toList(TraversableOnce.scala:242)
at scala.io.BufferedSource$BufferedLineIterator.toList(BufferedSource.scala:43)
at com.gmail.bernabe.laurent.scala.tests.DealWithFiles$.linesOfFile$1(DealWithFiles.scala:18)
at com.gmail.bernabe.laurent.scala.tests.DealWithFiles$$anonfun$grepFilesHere$2.apply(DealWithFiles.scala:23)
at com.gmail.bernabe.laurent.scala.tests.DealWithFiles$$anonfun$grepFilesHere$2.apply(DealWithFiles.scala:20)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$map$2.apply(TraversableLike.scala:697)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:34)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:38)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:696)   
at com.gmail.bernabe.laurent.scala.tests.DealWithFiles$.grepFilesHere(DealWithFiles.scala:20)
at com.gmail.bernabe.laurent.scala.tests.DealWithFiles$.main(DealWithFiles.scala:10)
at com.gmail.bernabe.laurent.scala.tests.DealWithFiles.main(DealWithFiles.scala)
```

Thanks in advance for helps :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From the JavaDoc:

> [MalformedInputException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/MalformedInputException.html)
>   thrown when an input byte sequence is not legal for given charset, or
>   an input character sequence is not a legal sixteen-bit Unicode
>   sequence.

Pass the currect encoding as parameter to `Source.fromFile` method.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think it is because I am under Debian, which use UTF8 encoding by default ? Thanks :). Also, I've tried Source.fromFile(file, "iso-8859-1").getLines.toList, which erase exception, but this time I still did not got the expected result (lines containing the regex ".*aur.*")

Comment: if you don't provide the `Charset`, JVM takes the default locale and charset of the underlying OS.

Answer (score 4):

You can handle this character encoding exception by adding below snippet in your code

```
import scala.io.Codec
import java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction


implicit val codec = Codec("UTF-8")
codec.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
codec.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
```