# RuntimeException: Malformed input around byte [...]

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

I decided to move my play framework project on a ubuntu machine. 
On **localhost**, the project ran perfectly, but on **Ubuntu**, I get the following issue:

> [RuntimeException: Malformed input around byte 455]

I know this mean there is a charset problem ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846848/why-do-i-get-a-malformedinputexception-from-this-code)), but how can I manage it? Or, at least, can I detect the exact place of the error in my code?

A big, big thank you in advance to you guys.

**Edit** Here is the complete stacktrace

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Malformed input around byte 455
>           at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
>           at scala.Predef$.error(Predef.scala:142)
>           at sbinary.JavaUTF$StringFormat$.malformed$1(javaprotocol.scala:109)
>           at sbinary.JavaUTF$StringFormat$.reads(javaprotocol.scala:142)
>           at sbinary.JavaUTF$StringFormat$.reads(javaprotocol.scala:100)
>           at sbinary.Operations$.read(operations.scala:9)
>           at sbinary.Generic$$anon$5.reads(generic.scala:71)
>           at sbinary.Operations$.read(operations.scala:9)
>           at sbinary.Generic$CollectionFormat$$anonfun$reads$1.apply(generic.scala:23)
>           at sbinary.Generic$CollectionFormat$$anonfun$reads$1.apply(generic.scala:23)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>           at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:141)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>           at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
>           at sbinary.Generic$CollectionFormat.reads(generic.scala:23)
>           at sbinary.Operations$.read(operations.scala:9)
>           at sbinary.Generic$$anon$2.reads(generic.scala:48)
>           at sbinary.Generic$$anon$2.reads(generic.scala:46)
>           at sbinary.Operations$.read(operations.scala:9)
>           at sbinary.BasicTypes$$anon$4.reads(standardtypes.scala:29)
>           at sbinary.BasicTypes$$anon$4.reads(standardtypes.scala:24)
>           at sbinary.Operations$.read(operations.scala:9)
>           at sbinary.Generic$CollectionFormat$$anonfun$reads$1.apply(generic.scala:23)
>           at sbinary.Generic$CollectionFormat$$anonfun$reads$1.apply(generic.scala:23)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>           at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:141)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>           at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
>           at sbinary.Generic$CollectionFormat.reads(generic.scala:23)
>           at sbinary.Operations$.read(operations.scala:9)
>           at sbinary.Generic$$anon$2.reads(generic.scala:48)
>           at sbinary.Generic$$anon$2.reads(generic.scala:46)
>           at sbinary.Operations$.read(operations.scala:9)
>           at sbinary.Generic$$anon$9.reads(generic.scala:123)
>           at sbinary.Operations$.read(operations.scala:9)
>           at sbinary.BasicTypes$$anon$4.reads(standardtypes.scala:28)
>           at sbinary.BasicTypes$$anon$4.reads(standardtypes.scala:24)
>           at sbinary.Operations$.read(operations.scala:9)
>           at sbt.Sync$$anonfun$readUncaught$1.apply(Sync.scala:89)
>           at sbt.Sync$$anonfun$readUncaught$1.apply(Sync.scala:88)
>           at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
>           at sbt.IO$$anonfun$gzipFileIn$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(IO.scala:783)
>           at sbt.IO$$anonfun$gzipFileIn$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(IO.scala:782)
>           at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
>           at sbt.IO$$anonfun$gzipFileIn$1.apply(IO.scala:782)
>           at sbt.IO$$anonfun$gzipFileIn$1.apply(IO.scala:781)
>           at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
>           at sbt.IO$.gzipFileIn(IO.scala:781)
>           at sbt.Sync$.readUncaught(Sync.scala:88)
>           at sbt.Sync$.readInfo(Sync.scala:84)
>           at sbt.Sync$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Sync.scala:29)
>           at sbt.Sync$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Sync.scala:23)
>           at com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb$.syncMappings(SbtWeb.scala:369)
>           at com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb$$anonfun$projectSettings$30.apply(SbtWeb.scala:182)
>           at com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb$$anonfun$projectSettings$30.apply(SbtWeb.scala:182)
>           at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
>           at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
>           at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
>           at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
>           at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
>           at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
>           at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
>           at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
>           at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
>           at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
>           at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [error] (web-assets:assets) Malformed input around byte 455 [error]
>   application -
>
> ! @6lap9p99l - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->
>
> play.PlayExceptions$UnexpectedException: Unexpected
>   exception[RuntimeException: Malformed input around byte 455]
>           at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$play$PlayReloader$$anon$$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReloader.scala:237)
>   ~[na:na]
>           at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$play$PlayReloader$$anon$$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReloader.scala:230)
>   ~[na:na]
>           at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
>           at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1.play$PlayReloader$$anon$$taskFailureHandler(PlayReloader.scala:230)
>   ~[na:na]
>           at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$reload$2.apply(PlayReloader.scala:90)
>   ~[na:na] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Malformed input around
>   byte 455
>           at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
>           at scala.Predef$.error(Predef.scala:142) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
>           at sbinary.JavaUTF$StringFormat$.malformed$1(javaprotocol.scala:109)
>   ~[na:na]
>           at sbinary.JavaUTF$StringFormat$.reads(javaprotocol.scala:142) ~[na:na]
>           at sbinary.JavaUTF$StringFormat$.reads(javaprotocol.scala:100) ~[na:na] [warn] play - No application found at invoker init

Comment: When exactly do you get this exception? At which point of running your application? Show us some stack trace if you see it

Comment: @Anton, I edited my message with the complete stacktrace.

Comment: @Mornor Probably is something in some CSS/JS files that is loaded when you access your controller. Check that those are saved in UTF

Comment: For any newbs to the framework, try running `sbt clean` if you encounter this.